# Docker container with KDB executable "No such file or directory"

Tags: docker, kdb

I am trying to use docker to run kdb/q. But I get a "No such file or directory" error

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

COPY ./ /root_dir/

WORKDIR root_dir

ENV QHOME=/root_dir/bin/q

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/root_dir/bin/q/l32/q"]

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

I am opening a bash command prompt just so I can take a look at it but eventually this would just be run with the q command directly

File Layout:

```
- root_dir
  - bin
    - q
      - q.k
      - s.k
      - l32
        - q
```

Build:

```
sudo docker build -t dfile -f Dockerfile .
```

Run:

```
sudo docker run -it dfile
```

Gives me a bash command prompt, and trying to launch q:

```
root@5e4b86578916:/root_dir# /root_dir/bin/q/l32/q
```

Gives

**bash: /root_dir/bin/q/l32/q: No such file or directory**

However I can see it there:

```
root@5e4b86578916:/root_dir# ls /root_dir/bin/q/l32/
q
```

How can I launch q/any executable from here?

NB: I am running q locally on Ubuntu with the same command, if I set QHOME to the same (local) location using export then give the full path to the executable I enter into a valid q session

Comment: Where does the `q` binary come from?  Is it the right OS, right architecture, and does it have any shared-library dependencies that aren't installed in the container?

Comment: The binary (and the other files in the tree) come from the 32 bit download of q https://code.kx.com/q/learn/install/, it is the right architecture up to 32/64 bit differences as I am running exactly the same locally - I am having a look at the 32/64 bit libraries now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it needs libc6-i386 to run (64 bit/32 bit conversion)

```
FROM ubuntu

COPY ./ /root_dir/

WORKDIR root_dir

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libc6-i386

ENV QHOME=/root_dir/bin/q

RUN chmod +x /root_dir/bin/q/l32/q

CMD /root_dir/bin/q/l32/q
```

Now works as expected. The only docs I can find are not very illuminating https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libc6-i386

Comment: (You generally need to `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` in the same command to avoid potential problems where the an old version of the APT package index is cached and doesn't reflect the actual `.deb` files available to download.)

Comment: Thank you, I am neither a debian or docker expert. Poking around in the dark really

Answer (score -2):

See [kdb install notes](https://code.kx.com/q/learn/install/#step-2-put-kdb-in-qhome) for how to run 32-bit kdb+ on 64-bit linux.

Comment: I cannot see anywhere on this page such information, can you either post here or be more specific please

Comment: Under step 2: https://code.kx.com/q/learn/install/#step-2-unzip-your-download
There is a block you can expand called "How to run 32-bit kdb+ on 64-bit Linux"


It contains the same solution: `sudo apt-get install libc6-i386`